# AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute 'CB' from bitsandbytes library when running the Mistral model on spark dataframe

Tags: large-language-model

Platform: Databricks
LLM Model: MistralAI-7B

I am trying to run a quantized LLM(4bit) model on a spark dataframe consisting of blocks of text and questions. As the model is quantized, some of the layers are on CPU and some of them are on GPU. I have created a Spark UDF to run the model inference on spark dataframe(20K rows). I am getting an error from BitsAndBytes library

```
An exception was thrown from the Python worker. Please see the stack trace below.
AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute 'CB'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/autograd/grad_mode.py", line 27, in decorate_context
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 1479, in generate
    return self.greedy_search(
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/generation/utils.py", line 2340, in greedy_search
    outputs = self(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/mistral/modeling_mistral.py", line 1154, in forward
    outputs = self.model(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/mistral/modeling_mistral.py", line 1039, in forward
    layer_outputs = decoder_layer(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/mistral/modeling_mistral.py", line 754, in forward
    hidden_states, self_attn_weights, present_key_value = self.self_attn(
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/cluster_libraries/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/models/mistral/modeling_mistral.py", line 255, in forward
    query_states = self.q_proj(hidden_states)
  File "/databricks/python/lib/python3.10/site-packages/torch/nn/modules/module.py", line 1194, in _call_impl
    return forward_call(*input, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/hooks.py", line 165, in new_forward
    output = module._old_forward(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-f335e7c4-adba-47d3-8a10-4fc922549da8/lib/python3.10/site-packages/bitsandbytes/nn/modules.py", line 443, in forward
    if self.weight.CB is not None:
AttributeError: 'Parameter' object has no attribute 'CB'
```

I tried to run on the sample of the rows but was getting the same error. I am suspecting it is due to quantization and the distribution of layers on GPU and CPU